# Setup Ubuntu Server 19.10 with MBR

Tags: server, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu Server on an old Mainboard. The Mainboard is not supported anymore and has problems booting from GPT media.

I'd like to use the whole disk for the Ubuntu installation. Is there an option to use the setup assistant and create a MBR media instead of a GPT one? I can't find it and I did not find something reasonable when googling the problem.

Comment: Is the computer UEFI... or only an old BIOS machine? How big is the HDD? What problems did you have booting from a GPT HDD? You can use `gparted` to first create a MBR partition table, then go back and install Ubuntu Server.

Comment: It is an old BIOS machine, the HDD is a 240 GB SSD and when trying to boot, the message "no bootable device found" comes up.

Comment: What brand SSD? Did you, or can you, use `gparted` to install a fresh MBR partition table on the SSD (this will wipe the drive), and then install Ubuntu Server? Some old BIOS machines can't boot if the boot files required are too far away from the front of the disk.

Comment: I created a blank MBR drive on the SSD (WD/Western Digital) and reinstalled Ubuntu, but Ubuntu switched the drive back to GPT. I could solve the problem by adding the active flag in the protective MBR, as described in my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem simply by setting the boot/active flag in the protective MBR. I expected the Ubuntu setup to do this by default.

To set the flag, I used `fdisk`. The command `fdisk -l` lists all the available devices, to identify the correct path (e.g. /dev/sda).

The command `fdisk /dev/sda` starts `fdisk` for editing the disk content. To add the boot/active flag, enter the following keys and then press return each time.

```
M    # Start Editing the Protective MBR
a    # Toggle Boot/Active Flag
w    # Write Changes
q    # Exit fdisk
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select an mbr during the installation.
even of ubuntu 22.04.

i let the installation to go to the disk partitioning.

it lets me to add a gpt partition only.

to make an mbr partition table,
i'm invoking cfdisk in the command line shell.
open the command line shell from the help button.
invoke cfdisk, that will let you choose the
disk format type.
choose mbr (or msdos) and write the partition table to the disk.

then exit the shell (with ctrl^d or exit).
your may choose to add an mbr partition (or msdos).

go ahead with your installation.