# updaing Windows Vista machine to Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, windows-vista

My first Ubuntu install, so I'm a little lost.

1. downloaded Ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64 from the website
2. downloaded Rufus 3.0
3. used Rufus to burn the file onto a memory stick

> Q: Does it matter where (what machine) step 3 takes place on? (because I was only able to download Ubuntu and Rufus on a different Windows 10 machine in-order to burn the memory stick)

4. went into my Vista machine BIOS and made sure it will start off of external disk
5. reboot machine with my memory stick plugged in

I have tried the load process 6 times and failed over and over, but for various reasons...

A) error 28 not enough space (even though I have 500GB and 4GB RAM on that machine)

B) install goes all the way and tells me it's complete, but upon reboot machine says No Operating System installed.

I hope I've included enough info, for what I'm sure is an extremely elementary issue...thanks in advance for any help that can be provided!

Comment: There is not way to update from Windows to Ubuntu. The only option is a clean install. It is not clear what you mean by "tried the load process 6 times". Load what and where? Does it mean to install, or to boot into Ubuntu from USB? It is also unclear which installation option is selected.  Is it dual boot or Ubuntu only, or is it manual?

Comment: Welcome! For the installation, you can follow [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview). Try it, and come back with any problem you encounter.

Comment: I was attempting a clean install, by "load the process" I mean, go through the Ubuntu load whre I'm asked to configure for the first time (choose language..etc).  I was attempting an Ubuntu only so Ubuntu would end up being my only operating system on that machine. (sorry for not having covered these in the intial post, I will get better at posting my questions in the future)

Comment: thanks schrodigerscatcuriosity! I'll try following the link.

Comment: I've read/folowed the installation guide above. this time I tried to install the deskop version of Ubuntu as opposed to server.  the load is successful but when I reboot the machine says no operating system found. I'm not sure if this may be related to the way the disk is configured on this machine.  perhaps when machine loads it tries to load from a partition that does not have the OS on it???

BTW, next time I try to load Ubantu again, it confirms that Ubantu exists on this machine and asks me if I want to over write it confirming that previous load was succesful

Comment: BTW, I'm able to load Ubuntu and via the "try" path, by loading directly from USB.   this leads me to believe my issue is that my efibootmgr is somehow trying to load from the wrong location.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, the link you provided was helpful in getting the ball rolling in the right direction.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: does it matter where (what machine) step 3 takes place on?

No, but since your machine has Windows Vista, I must ask if its processor is 64bit or 32bit...

If its 32bit you could try install Xenial
https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Also, maybe you should be installing the desktop image?

> my first Ubuntu install

Server image will not install a graphical user interface.

As for your problem:
The "no operating system found" is not an ubuntu message. If your machine has more then one hard drive I would check for wrong bios boot configurations, else, check this post: [Setup Ubuntu Server 19.10 with MBR](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202525/setup-ubuntu-server-19-10-with-mbr)

Comment: so the latest as of last night was that the Ubuntu load would complete and give me the option to reboot, but after rebooting my machine would still report "no operating system found". (another issue is that this is unstable, as every other load will fail half way through the load process)

the machine is a 64bit, Intel Core 2 Duo P8600 / 2.4 GHz, with 4GHz of RAM...I had in the past used the Ubuntu VM Desktop image, and really wanted to force myslef off of the GUI, and given that this is an older machine I figured going with the server was a better idea in order to take up less space/memmory

Comment: There are very light desktop environments that you may try, even on top of your server installation, like LXDE (used on LUbuntu), Xfce (used on XUbuntu) ...

Comment: Miguel, yes the issue appeared to be related to wrong BIOS config.  I had to follow a multi step to get around it.
1.I switched over to Ubuntu desktop 
2.I proceeded with the 'Try' option which loads Ubutnu from the usb drive
3.I them loaded the perminent version from within Ubuntu

it's possible that when I was trying to load the server I was making incorrect choices when option was given to configure the hard-drive, but to be honest I did not want to unmount and try to recreate issue as I had lost 2 days already.

Thanks for your help!